# SQLCipher Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x756c66f2 (code=1)

Tags: android, database, sqlite, sqlcipher

I am developing an Android app with SQLite and want to change to an encrypted database with SQLcipher.
I added icudt46l.zip to the assets folder and *.so to the libs/armeabi folder.
As it's an upgrade, I want to encrypt the unencrypted database.

I tested the code on a Samsung S2 (Android 2.3.3) and a Sony Z1 (Android 4.4.2) and it works correctly, the update from an unencrypted database as well with a new encrypted database.
With my Samsung Galaxy S4 (Android 4.2.2) I constantly get a Fatal signal 11 when I try to open the unencrypted database    `SQLiteDatabase db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(originalFile, "", null)`    .
It's the first call of a SQLcipher-method in my code (besides    `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(inContext)`    ).
If I'm changing the package-name from the manifest it runs on the S4 (so it gets a fresh clean database).
As I thought of an OOM-Exception I tested the code on the S2 again. I generated an 10MB SQLite unencrypted database and transformed it with my code correctly.

Can anyone give me a hint, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the guy here has the same Problem, maybe it helps.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlcipher/hZFpNSSP-c8